# Is there a "goto" equivalent in Freemarker?

Tags: syntax, freemarker, goto

Does Freemarker have a "goto" equivalent to be able to jump to a specific line of code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no goto-like jumping in FreeMarker. Flow control is done by `#if`/`#elseif`/`#else`, and `#list`/`#break`/`#continue`, and by calling `#macro`-s and `#function`-s, and by `#return` inside macros/functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template include or macro definition call to achieve different conditions to render different fragments

Comment: Please try to give more information, if possible with some example codes.

Comment: @JithinScaria <#if a?has_content> <#include 'a.ftl'/></#if>